# Provider is invalid on Polygon testnet

Tags: ethers.js

I'm having a strange problem.
I deployed to a contract on the polygon testnet using hardhat

```
const config: HardhatUserConfig = {
  defaultNetwork: "polygon_mumbai",
  networks: {
    hardhat: {
    },
    polygon_mumbai: {
      url: "https://rpc-mumbai.maticvigil.com",
      accounts: [process.env.PRIVATE_KEY!]
    }
  },
  etherscan: {
    apiKey: process.env.POLYGONSCAN_API_KEY
  },
  solidity: {
    version: "0.8.9",
    settings: {
      optimizer: {
        enabled: true,
        runs: 200
      }
    }
  },
};
import { ethers } from "hardhat";

async function main() {
  const Wallet = await ethers.getContractFactory("Wallet");
  const wallet = await Wallet.deploy();

  const deployed = await wallet.deployed();
  console.log(deployed);
}
```

And when I try to use the contract in my react native application using ethers js I get the following error

```
 invalid provider (argument="provider", value="EtherscanProvider", code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=wallet/5.7.0)
```

```
const privateKey: object | string = await getAsyncData('privateKey');
            // @ts-ignore
            const signer = new ethers.Wallet(privateKey);
            console.log(signer.provider);
            const contract = new ethers.Contract(CONTRACT_ADDRESS, abi, signer.provider);
            console.log(await contract.getNumOfUsers());
```

The provider really comes null
Do you know how I could solve this error?